# Update String inside object inside array mongodb

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose

I have a document that looks something like this

```
{

    "_id":{
        "$oid":"id"
    },
    "side1":[
        {
            "username":"test1",
            "id":"id1",
            
        },
        {
            "username":"test2",
            "id":"id2",
            
        },
        {
            "username":"test3",
            "id":"id3",
            
        }
       
    ],
    "side2":[
        {
            "username":"test4",
            "id":"id4",
            
        },
        {
            "username":"test5",
            "id":"id5",
            
        },
        {
            "username":"test6",
            "id":"id6",
            
        }
        
    ],


}
```

I want to be able to search and update one of the sides, for example, if I searched with username for side1 and that username would be there then I would be able to $set other fields for the object with this username. Something like: `Search side1 username test1: $set result.id: "43242342"` this would set the id of the object with the username of test1 to 43242342. I am not sure on how I would go about doing this, I have tried using $elemMatch but that didn't bring any results.

```
Test.findOne({ id: id }, 
                
                { side1: { $elemMatch: {username: username} } }, function (err, result) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                } else {
                    console.log(result)
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure how you want to update the document, but perhaps this is what you are looking for?

```js
db.collection.update({
  "_id": ObjectId("000000000000000000000001"),
  "side1.username": "test1"
},
{
  "$set": {
    "side1.$.id": "43242342"
  }
})
```

Try it on [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/x2PT5Pi0bgu).

Example updated document:

```json
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("000000000000000000000001"),
    "side1": [
      {
        "id": "43242342",
        "username": "test1"
      },
      {
        "id": "id2",
        "username": "test2"
      },
      {
        "id": "id3",
        "username": "test3"
      }
    ],
    "side2": [
      {
        "id": "id4",
        "username": "test4"
      },
      {
        "id": "id5",
        "username": "test5"
      },
      {
        "id": "id6",
        "username": "test6"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you do something like this?

```
function addProperty(id, side, username, property, value) {
  const query = {
    _id: {
      $oid: id,
    },
  };

  const update = {
    $push: {
      [side]: {
        username: username,
        [property]: value,
      },
    },
  };

  const options = {
    upsert: true,
  };

  db.collection("Test").updateOne(query, update, options);
}
```

Comment: Can't really get this to work